# Handle access token in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

I have Web Api and AngularJS to consume web Api.

when user login with credential user get access_token and refresh token with issued and expires field.

access_token is expired in each 1 minutes and allocate new token to user.

now the problem is

> The time between token expired and allocation of new token to user.
>
> if user do a page refresh then its makes an api call to load data of that page, but the access token was just expired and user does not got a new token, so old token is set in header of api call, hence user got **401 unauthorized** as response and application throw user to log out.

I am using token in first time so not have much information about access_token and refresh_token

So, I do not know how to handle this situation.

advises is appreciable.

Comment: Its simple just make the token request api call on page load and after that call is complete then only initilaise the angular app

Comment: that means each time user reload page its make an api call for token, but I only want to assign new token when user reload page and got 401 status code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Kushal and @sahil to provide idea.

When user's token is expired app redirect them to login page so on login page  added api call to fetch token by user's refresh_token and if user has correct refresh token then assign them to new token and redirect to page which user refreshed by tracking / maintain log of current page of user are. and its working.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you make an API call to load data on the page, in the `callback` you should check the `status code`. If the `status code` is `401`, get the `refresh token` and then make another call to the same API and then only initialize the app. Otherwise initialize the app with the `old response` value.

Comment: `get the refresh token` that means have to add `refresh token` in header of api call ?

Comment: This means you set the new token generated, in the header and make the same api call again

Comment: is there any way to write callback function to all api call, because I don't know on which user is. And is good idea to write an api call to get token in callback function ?